# Object doesn't support property or method 'kendoDatePicker'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, telerik

I created a new project with MV5 Razor, but i can't run "@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datapickerTest"))" in my home page view, i have include "Kendo .js" and "jquery 2.1.3", but doesn't work.

Reference "Kendo.Mvc" is included at project.

BundleConfig.cs :

```
    public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.all.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.timezones.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/css").Include(
        "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css",
        "~/Content/kendo/kendo.common.min.css",
        "~/Content/kendo/kendo.default.min.css",
        "~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.min.css",
        "~/Content/kendo/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css",
        "~/Content/kendo/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"));

        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

        // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
        // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml :

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Comment: SOLVED. I founded in footer of my "_Layout.cshtml :" page this "    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED. I founded in footer of my "_Layout.cshtml :" page this " @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")"

Comment: yeah this one is the culprit